# asynchronous search promises not resolving in order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await

My problem here is that the fetching promises that where created a few characters earlier then the current text **resolves later then the last promise** created.
I need the last promise to be resolved the latest or cancel previous pending promises when I change the text.

I would like the results to always the latest fetch.

I looked up some searchbar examples but couldn't find anything.

I am quite certain the solution would be to save the previous promise and cancel it if it is still pending when you create a new promise, but I have no idea how to cancel promises.

Thanks for helping.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, Fragment} from "react";

function TestComponent () {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            await getResults();
        })();
    }, [text]);
    
    async function getResults() {
        let resultsFromFetch = await fetch('url');
        resultsFromFetch = await resultsFromFetch.json();
        setResults(resultsFromFetch);
    }
    
    function onChange(evt) {
        setText(evt.target.value);
    }
    
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <input type="text" value={text} onChange={onChange}/>
            {results.map((value, index) => {
                return <p key={index}>{value}</p>;
            })}
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default TestComponent;
```

Note: in the real problem I have I don't use fetch but just an asynchronous indexeddb operation.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is denounce. Debounce doesn't run a function until it reaches a certain threshold. All other functions that run before the threshold do not run.

Comment: @RohitKashyap This would indeed work but if the difference between the resolving of multiple promises is bigger then your debounce rate this could still cause problems. I think canceling the promise or at least not calling the setResults when its not the last promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, it doesn't really cancel the promise but it stops the function from setting the results.

Add an extra state variable: `const [cancelToken, setCancelToken] = useState(null);`

Change the effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (cancelToken) {
        cancelToken.cancel(); // execute the cancel function of the previous search
    }

    let newCancelToken = {}; // create an empty object to pass into the getResults function

    getResults(cancelToken);

    setCancelToken(newCanelToken); // change the state variable to the new cancel token
}, [text]);
```

Change the getResults function:

```
async function getResults(newCancelToken) {
    let canceled = false; // create a local canceled variable
    newCancelToken.cancel = () => {
        canceled = true; // change it to true when the cancel function is called
    };
    let resultsFromFetch = await fetch('url');
    resultsFromFetch = await resultsFromFetch.json();

    if (!canceled) {
         setResults(resultsFromFetch); // only change the state if it is not canceled
    }
   
}
```